# Best way to pass a POJO to a spring MVC controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have done a few MVC controllers now and used the spring form tags to pass data back and forth but I realise now my actual understanding is a little thin.  In my current case I could actually just send the response as url parameters but there are about 15 and I would prefer to send it as a pojo if possible.

My actual question... is ... is it possible to set up a spring style model attribute in a jsp without the attribute having been passed in and without using the form tags ?

So for example something along the lines of

```
//Pojo 
 Class personclass 
 {
   private String name + getters and setters
   private String address + getters and setters
   private String phone + getters and setters
   ...
  }

 ////first mvc call
 @RequestMapping ("/")
 Public ModelAndView LandingPage()
 {
   // no mention of Person pbject
   Return mandvobject;
  }

  //jsp page
  //This is the question!
  SET ModelAttribute that wasn't passed in to the page
  personclass = X 
  //New MVC call without a submit 
   window.open ("/NewMVCCall")


  //New mvc call
  @RequestMapping ("/NewMVCCall")
  Public void newMVCPage(@ModelAttribute ("pc") personclass pc, Model model)
  {
     //process pc object
   }
```

Or am I missing the point and I would have to send it as a json string parameter?  Sorry my grasp of this is pretty rudimentary and I'm not sure whether I could quite easily set my own http form content or whether it is because I have used Spring form objects so far that I haven't grasped the complexity of what is going on behind the scenes (i.e form tags converting pojos to json and so on) ?

Many thanks if anyone has the time to set me on the right path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I am understood your question correctly but you can link a Model to your controller without having to manually pass it to a the view every time you need it, spring will take care of that:

in your Controller :

```
public class MyController{

      @ModelAttribute("pc")
      public PersonneClass getPersonnelClass(){
        return new PersonneClass();
      }

     @RequestMapping ("/NewMVCCall")
     Public void newMVCPage(@ModelAttribute ("pc") personclass pc, Model model)
     {
        //process pc object
     }
  //other methods

}
```

It is a good practice to stick to java conventions when naming classes so
     (personneClass ) must start with an uppercase (PersonneClass) .

Comment: I think that is what I'm looking for, I haven't seen the @modelAttribute get function before.  I take it I would then do a page import of the PersonClass into the jsp page.  Sorry to ask but how would I then add it to the window.open ("/NewMVCCall") ?  Would it be a parameter or a <c:set... > or would I need to edit the httpRequest/Response ?

Comment: @gringogordo I think that what you are looking for is an ajax call to `/NewMVCCall` , affterring setting the properties of your from , you can submit it using ajax . is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes I think that's it thanks! I was thinking to do it without a form (series of questions in jquery dialog) and I was missing how to send the data without a form. If I put a form in with modelattribute personclass, presumably I can set the personclass properties manually (rather than databinding) and then, as you say, post the form with ajax. Do you think this is right? (The form will be incorporated automatically in a $.ajax({type: "POST", url... call.  )? Sorry to take so much of your time, I've been around the houses a bit and I'm trying to make sure I have it right now...